# Tesseract 3.04.00 on mac, ERROR "can not open input file"

Tags: tesseract

I am working in a Terminal on OSX. The file name is `sample` and it is a `png` file. Tesseract creates an `out.txt` file in my current directory, but it's empty. I have tried commands with different file types, such as `tiff`, and also tried entering the full input file path, but the same error occurs.

What does the error mean?

```
eugeneprokopenko$ tesseract sample out
```

> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica
>
> ERROR: Can not open input file sample
>
> Error during processing.

Comment: I can't tell for sure from your description but have you tried adding the file extension to `sample` (e.g. `tesseract sample.png out`)?

Comment: Thanks @adilapapaya, I have tried that. I'll keep playing with it and will post if I figure it out

Comment: Thanks again @adilapapaya, after adding extension to both the file and the command line, it worked this time ... not sure what I was doing wrong the first time, but thanks for the help. Too bad the .txt output is kind of messy. I'll have to work on that.